# how do I change the background color of up triangle when I hover a submenu one

Tags: jquery, css, hover, pseudo-element

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buLy7/)

```
#nav .submenu:before {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-bottom: 22px solid #b29600; 
   border-left: 11px solid transparent; 
   border-right: 11px solid transparent;    
   margin: -12px 0 0 -55px;
}
```

I have posted my codes on jsfiddle. When I hover a main menu it will show the sub menus. I have a up triangle in top of the submenu. When I hover a submenu 1 it changes the bg color but, that up triangle doesn't change its color. How do I change the background color of up triangle when I hover a submenu 1?

Answer (score 1):

Are you okay with JS solution? You can add/remove class on hover which will change the color of triangle.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/buLy7/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.submenu li a').on('mouseover', function () {
    $(this).parents('.submenu:first').addClass('temp');
});
$('.submenu li a').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).parents('.submenu:first').removeClass('temp');
});
});
```

I used `temp` classname for changing the colors.

CSS:

```
#nav .submenu.temp:before {
 border-bottom: 22px solid red;/*Your color*/
}
```

In case of multiple submenu:
JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.a').on('mouseover', function () {
    console.log('in');
    $(this).parents('.submenu:first').addClass('temp');
});
$('.a').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $('.temp').removeClass('temp');
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Main</a>

        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a class="a" href="#">Sub 1</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a>

            </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
     <li><a href="#">Main</a>

        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a class="a" href="#">Sub 1</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a>

            </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Changes:**: Added a class to first anchor in `.submenu` and then binded events to it.

Comment: It works. Actually, you have used same border color in both styles. Change the color and you'll see the difference. Also, it should be '.submenu li:first a' instead of '.submenu li a:first'

Comment: Can you provide the jsfiddle for multiple menu? You can probably add a same class to each menu and then mouseover mouseleave events to it

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/buLy7/5/ ? second menu triangle color not changing. ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. It will change the Triangle Color when you hover a submenu.

```
#nav .submenu:hover:before {  border-bottom: 22px solid #4C4000; }
```

If you want specific for First option in sub menu then you have to do it with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

If you move the pseudo-element to the first-child LI, then it's achievable in CSS, like so:

```
#nav .submenu li:first-child:before {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-bottom: 22px solid #b29600; 
   border-left: 11px solid transparent; 
   border-right: 11px solid transparent;    
   margin: -12px 0 0 -0px;
}


#nav .submenu li:first-child:hover:before {  border-bottom: 22px solid #4C4000; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/36yqr/